# Will panoramio layer disappear from maps built with google maps api on June4?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I understand that the Panoramio layer will continue to work until June 4, 2015 only. I have built several google map websites using the Panoramio layer. Does the closure of Panoramio library mean that my websites will not work after June 4? Also, will Panoramio disappear from (classic) google maps on June 4?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes and Yes.
You can read the [announce](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2014/06/sunsetting-javascript-api-weather-panoramio.html) and [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-panoramio) but also don't find a word from Panoramio hinself but this [terms of service](http://www.panoramio.com/api/terms.html) are linked to google terms itself (and it's deprecation police) and it's enough to force us to say goodbye Panoramio.